# Display custom TableView cells using plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, tableview

I want to display a small image and date inside of a Table View cell, which the user can click on to display another view with more information. All of this data is stored in a plist (image, date, and other numbers).

I can't seem to:

1. Get the images to display inside of the cells - I added all of my images into the Supporting Files folder and tried to enter the filenames into the plist which it did not accept.
2. Add the functionality for the user to click on a cell and view more information from the plist data.

Comment: you must add your code if you want somebody to help you with it.

Comment: I haven't written any code.

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Comment: 1) Get the images to display inside of the cells - I added all of my images into the Supporting Files folder and tried to enter the filenames into the plist which it did not accept. *How do I display images located in Supporting files from a plist?

2) Add the functionality for the user to click on a cell and view more information from the plist data. *What code do I need to display this new view with data from the plist?

Comment: People on here are a lot more willing to help if they see you've tried some effort. Otherwise, it will look a homework assignment someone is trying to get a solution for with little effort. Try doing something first and coming back when you run into issues (paste code, highlight where it's not working, etc).

Comment: I don't understand. There isn't much code involved here, and I simply don't know how to go about it. I have looked at various tutorials but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you construct your "database" using plist which contains an array of dictionary. This should be something like this:

[image]

Create and `NSArray` to hold this plist:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imagesList;
```

And do the loading in `viewDidLoad` (suppose that the plist named "ImagesList"):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImagesList" ofType:@"plist"];
self.imagesList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The rest is some simple `UITableViewDatasource`:

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDatasource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.imagesList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *eachImage = [self.imagesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [eachImage objectForKey:@"date"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [eachImage objectForKey:@"additionalDetail"];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[eachImage objectForKey:@"imageName"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Don't forget to put your images into app bundle and rename it properly.

Comment: When I change self.imagesList to the name of my plist, it says that a property [plistName] not found on object of type View Controller? Also, under which file does the UITableViewDataSource code go under?

Comment: Did you create the plist file? The UITableViewDataSource is in the controller which manage your table view.

Comment: Yes I created the plist file; so you mean the UITableViewDataSource is in the .h View Controller or .m View Controller file?